# 日本語に違和感: ユーザーによる貢献は、cc by-sa 3.0 (要属性) (コンテンツ ポリシー)でライセンスされています

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 日本語

### 投稿編集フォームの画像アップロードダイアログ

[image: 画像アップロードダイアログ]

### サイトフッター

> ユーザーによる貢献は、cc by-sa 3.0 でライセンスされています (要属性)

Comment: 翻訳両方登録しました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### 投稿編集フォームの画像アップロードダイアログ

> ユーザーによる貢献は、cc by-sa 3.0 (要属性) (コンテンツ ポリシー)でライセンスされています
>   ↓
>   ユーザー投稿コンテンツにはクリエイティブ・コモンズ 表示-継承 3.0 (要クレジット表記) のライセンスが適用されます (コンテンツポリシー)

- 「ユーザーによる貢献」「要属性」に違和感があったため言い換えました
- cc by-sa 3.0 を日本語表記にしました (わかりやすくするため)
- 「これからあなたがアップロードする画像にはライセンスが適用されますよ」という雰囲気を出すため、「されています」→「されます」に言い換えました

### サイトフッター

> ユーザーによる貢献は、cc by-sa 3.0 でライセンスされています (要属性)
>   ↓
>   ユーザー投稿コンテンツはクリエイティブ・コモンズ 表示-継承 3.0 のもとでライセンスされており、 2 次利用にはクレジット表記が必要です

- 「ユーザーによる貢献」「要属性」に違和感があったため言い換えました
- cc by-sa 3.0 を日本語表記にしました (わかりやすくするため)
- 原文の "attribution required" のリンク先になっている記事の意図を汲んで、「2次利用にはクレジット表記が必要です」と説明的にしてみました

---

参考: [creativecommons.jpのフッター](http://creativecommons.jp/): 「このサイトの内容物はクリエイティブ・コモンズ・ライセンス 表示 2.1のもとでライセンスされています。」